# Maven cannot resolve dependency

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit

I am very much confused, for it seems I have done everything right.

I am trying to build a maven hello world project with IDEA. I have my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.anarion</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenDemo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

My directories:

[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3HQr.png)

The test class has been placed under a test directory. HelloMavenTest.java:

```
package com;

import static org.junit.*;

public class HelloMavenTest {
    @org.junit.Test
    public void hello() {

    }
}
```

The ide keeps giving me this error:

```
java: package org.junit does not exist
```

I dont know where I got it wrong...

Comment: From the command line are you able to run `mvn test`?

Answer (score 0):

As per the following link https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit, it says

> Note: This artifact was moved to:
>
> org.junit.jupiter » junit-jupiter-api

You can also use the following dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

You can check the link.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.0.3

Comment: Still doesn't work... I see a 'broken classes path' error in project structure... Dont know what it is...

Comment: I figured it out. The path to the bundled maven of IDEA is invalid under Mac OSX...